# Node.JS - SQL Injection in URL parameters?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, security, sql-injection

I'm trying to learn Node.js and I'm currently making an Express app (using ejs) that will return values from a **MySQL database**, depending on the URL the user visits.

For example, visiting `http://localhost:3000/test` will list all users from the db table `users`. And the link `http://localhost:3000/test/3` will return information about the user with the id number 3.

My code for: **/test**

```
app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY name";
    db.query(sql, function (err, results, fields) {
        if (err)
            logmessage(err.message);
        
        res.render("test", { data: results });
    });
});
```

And here is the code for **/test/:id**

```
app.get("/test/:id", (req, res) => {
    var userId = req.params.id;

    let sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " + userId;
    db.query(sql, function (err, results, fields) {
        if (err || !results.length) {
            res.redirect("/");
        } else {
            res.render("test_user", { data: results });
        }
    });
});
```

My question is: is this safe? When I previously worked in PHP development, I used to prepare statements before making any queries.

What happens if a user changes the URL from: `http://localhost:3000/test/3` and inserts some SQL injection code at the end of the url? Can the database be breached?

This will be for a live app on the web, so it's important no SQL injection can be made. I also want to add a form later on (req.body instead of req.params) that I also need to sanitize.

Or is there a built-in "prepared statement" already in Node?

Comment: No it's not safe. See your sql libraries documentation on how to properly create prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection is prevented if you use [placeholders](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values):

```js
let sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
db.query(sql, [userId], function (err, results, fields) {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement Sequelize? From what I read ORMs prevent SQL injection. Also, it's pretty easy to use :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).